# Accessing stored attributes in ExactTarget SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, mobilepush-android, sdk

I'm using the JB4A Android SDK. It seems that the ETPush class exposes a method called `getAttributes()` which returns an `ArrayList` of the key-value pair attributes that are sent to the server. I want to check to see if my list contains a certain key and conditionally add it if it does not exist.

The problem is that the `ArrayList` returned by `ETPush.getInstance().getAttributes()` provides a list of `Objects` instead of `Attribute`s. It seems that the SDK also does not expose this `Attribute` class, so even though I can see these objects in the debugger, I can't use them in code.

Is there some way to access these objects in such a way that can be used?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get to your desired attribute with `getAttributes()` (see below), however, the method name is a little misleading as `addAttribute()` actually will add or update an attribute.

Calling `etPush.addAttribute("someKey", "someValue");` a hundred times over will only ever result in 1 `Attribute` with the key value pair noted above.

```
import com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.data.Attribute;

public class SomeClass {
  public void someMethod() {
    ETPush etPush = ETPush.getInstance();
    Attribute targetAttribute;
    ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = etPush.getAttributes();
    for (Attribute attribute : attributes) {
      if (attribute.getKey().equals("someKey")) {
        targetAttribute = attribute;
        break;
    }
    if (targetAttribute == null) {
      etPush.addAttribute("someKey", "someValue");
    }
  }
}
```